# Using ServiceStack Funq IoC: how dependencies are injected?

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, servicestack-bsd

I have WinForm application and I want to use ServiceStack dependency injection mechanism:

```
public class AppHost : AppHostBase
{
    public AppHost()
        : base("MyName", typeof(AppHost).Assembly)
    {
    }

    public override void Configure(Container container)
    {
        container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<AppApplicationContext, IAppApplicationContext>();
    }
}
```

Then in some form class use it:

```
public class SomeClass : AppBaseForm
{
    public IAppApplicationContext AppApplicationContext { get; set; }

    public SomeClass(IAppApplicationContext appApplicationContext)
    {
        AppApplicationContext = appApplicationContext;
    }

    public SomeClass()
    {
    }
}
```

But `AppApplicationContext` is always `null`. When in parameterless constructor I write:

```
AppApplicationContext = AppHostBase.Resolve<IAppApplicationContext>();
```

then every thing is OK. But is this right way to do that? I mean AppApplicationContext should not be resolved by IoC automatically? And WinForm must have parameterless constructor.

Rest of code:

```
private static void Main()
{
    var appHost = new AppHost();
    appHost.Init();
}

public interface IAppApplicationContext
{
}

public class AppApplicationContext : IAppApplicationContext
{
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to call `AutoWire` to have the container inject the dependancies. You can use it in your WinForm app like this:

```cs
public class SomeClass : AppBaseForm
{
    public IAppApplicationContext AppApplicationContext { get; set; }

    public SomeClass()
    {
        // Tell the container to inject dependancies
        HostContext.Container.AutoWire(this);
    }
}
```

When you use a regular ServiceStack service, the `AutoWire` happens behind the scenes during the request pipeline when ServiceStack creates an instances of your Service.

I have created a [fully working example here](https://gist.github.com/scottmcarthur/8750037). *Note: The demo is just a console application, not WinForms but it does shows the IoC being used outside of the ServiceStack service, and it works no differently.*

Comment: That was that kind of magic what I was looking for. Btw I'm still using 3.x, sorry for wrong tagging. `AppHostBase.Instance.Container.AutoWire(this);` in my case do the trick.